# How to iterate over a list of items to use it in c.Search method of twint library and save the output into separate files?

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to collect some data from twitter using `twint` library.

I've a list of `search_terms` and I want to take each value from this list and call c.Search on each value. I tried the below method, but I get output only for `aclens` value and only that is saved in csv format.

What am I doing wrong? Please correct me if am wrong in writing the code for output as well.

This is my code:

```py
import twint
import os

search_terms = ['abchome','adidas','aclens']

def jobone():
    c = twint.Config()
    for i in range(len(search_terms)):
        c.Search = search_terms[i]
        c.Lang = "en"
        c.Since = "2019-07-01 00:00:00"
        c.Limit = 3000
        c.Store_csv = True
    for filename in search_terms:
        c.Output = os.path.join('../data/{}.csv'.format(filename))

    twint.run.Search(c)

jobone()
```

Expected Output:

3 csv files stored separately with the names given in the `search_terms` with tweets in those csv files.

Comment: You have a loop within a loop. You just want 1 loop, where all the configuraiton and running is. Re-read and be careful where what happens, inside or outside the loop.

Comment: @user3184950 Thank you! I just solved this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code should be:

```py
import twint
import os

search_terms = ['abchome','aclens']

def jobone():
    for i in range(len(search_terms)):
        c = twint.Config()
        c.Search = search_terms[i]
        c.Lang = "en"
        c.Since = "2019-07-01 00:00:00"
        c.Limit = 100
        c.Store_csv = True
        c.Output = os.path.join('../data/{}.csv'.format(search_terms[i]))
        # c.Debug = True
        # c.Resume = "twint-last-request.log"

        twint.run.Search(c)

jobone()
```